# foreach returns more elements than count()

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, iterator

I'm using Symfony 1.2.7 and Doctrine 1.1. I have `$activities (sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator - Doctrine_Collection)`. I'm escaping everything on settings.yml with ESC_SPECIALCHARS method. If I weren't escaping it, it would work without any problem, so I think the problem is related with `sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator`.

If I do `echo count($activities)` it returns me **5**

I remove several elements:

```
foreach($activities as $key => $a){
  if(...){
    $activities->remove($key);
  }
}
```

Then if I do `echo count($activities)` it returns me **2**

However when I iterate through the elements, I still have the same 5 elements:

```
foreach($activities as $activity){
  ..
}
```

Any idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
foreach($activities as $key => $a){
  if(...){
    unset($activitie[$key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: although it's not technically the answer, it has inspired me to take a new approach. It seems that the sfOutputEscaperIteratorDecorator collection is read only so I can't remove elements (although it seems that its counter works in a different way). What I now do is adding the elements to a different array, and then unset() the elements I don't want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's also array_splice()